# Merging similar columns from different files into a matrix

Tags: shell, matrix, awk, multiple-columns

I have the files with following format each with the first column being common amongst all the files:

```
  File1.txt
  ID    Score            
  ABCD   0.9
  BCBS   0.2
  NBNC   0.67
  TCGS   0.8

  File2.txt
  ID    Score            
  ABCD   0.3
  BCBS   0.9
  NBNC   0.73
  TCGS   0.12

  File3.txt
  ID    Score            
  ABCD   0.23
  BCBS   0.65
  NBNC   0.94
  TCGS   0.56
```

I want to merge the second column (Score column) of all the files with the first column being common and display the file name minus the extension of each file as the header to identify as to where did the score come from such that the matrix would look something like

```
   ID     File1  File2 File3
  ABCD     0.9   0.3   0.23
  BCBS     0.2   0.9   0.65        
  NBNC     0.67  0.73  0.94          
  TCGS     0.8   0.12  0.56
```

Comment: So, what have you tried and where are you having problems?  Are the lines in each file guaranteed to be in the same order, so there's no need to work out which score belongs to which ID?  Have you tried doing it with just 10 files?  360k columns means that line lengths will be over 1 MiB each; that might stress programs.

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler I tried to build up a past command for all files and pipe it to awk, but I know that it would be a pathetic way to go about it for so many files, and yes the order is exactly the same!

Comment: Edit your question to show, say, 3 **small** (eg. each 3 or 4 rows by 3 or 4 columns) input files and the expected output given that input. You can scale it yourself from 3 to 194 files and 3 or 4 to 364893 columns once you get the answer.

Comment: Note that the original version of the question started "I have 194 files with following format having 364893 columns each with the first column being common amongst all the files".  That triggered my observation about megabyte line lengths which the revision clearly does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
FNR>1 { id[FNR] = $1; score[FNR,ARGIND] = $2 }
END {
    printf "%s%s", "ID", OFS
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=ARGIND; colNr++) {
        sub(/\..*/,"",ARGV[colNr])
        printf "%s%s", ARGV[colNr], (colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=2; rowNr<=FNR; rowNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", id[rowNr], OFS
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=ARGIND; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", score[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt
ID      File1   File2   File3
ABCD    0.9     0.3     0.23
BCBS    0.2     0.9     0.65
NBNC    0.67    0.73    0.94
TCGS    0.8     0.12    0.56
```

Pick some string that can't occur in your input as the OFS, I used tab.

If you don't have GNU awk add `FNR==1{ ARGIND++ }` at the start of the script.

Comment: Ed, I have 194 such files and they are not exactly named as file1 , file2 so forth , I was trying to use the same code on 194 files as  awk -f merge.awk  *_max.txt assuming it would pick up files with same extension and merge them together, however since the process is too long it is getting killed, do you have any suggestions? TIA

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative

```
$ awk 'NR==1{$0=$1"\t"FILENAME}1' File1 > all; 
  for f in File{2..6}; 
     do 
       paste all <(p $f) > temp && cp temp all; 
     done
```

define function p as

```
p() { awk 'NR==1{print FILENAME;next} {print $2}' $1; }
```

I copied your data to 6 identical files File1..File6 and the script produced this.  Most of the work is setting up the column names

```
ID      File1   File2   File3   File4   File5   File6
  ABCD   0.9    0.9     0.9     0.9     0.9     0.9
  BCBS   0.2    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
  NBNC   0.67   0.67    0.67    0.67    0.67    0.67
  TCGS   0.8    0.8     0.8     0.8     0.8     0.8
```